# Stop Git from pushing secret (but tracked) files

Tags: git, push, git-submodules, git-remote

Using `git` I track a top secret file called `top-secret.txt`.
How can I ensure that this file never leaves my local system when pushing
to a remote (but stays under version control locally)?

**Example**

- Let's say I have a commit which changes the secret file called `top-secret.txt` *and* another file called `not-secret.txt`.
- When pushing this commit *only* the change made to `not-secret.txt` shall be transferred to the remote.
- The change made to `top-secret.txt` shall stay on my local system.

**Extra info:**
Pushing is performed by a Continuous Integration System so I have the chance to execute scripts locally before pushing to the remote.

Do I need to setup a git submodule for this or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Why do you need to track the history of a file that only you can access?

Comment: @JérômeBrunel In order to track changes, keep a version history and for some other key features of version control systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  Git's underlying object model (that everything is an object of one of four types: commit, tree, annotated-tag, or "blob"—i.e., file) prohibits distinguishing between "file I can see but you can't" and "file everyone can see".  Anyone with a copy of the repository can see every object in the repository.

There are therefore only two ways to keep a file secret:

- don't include it in the repository in the first place, or
- encrypt it.

The submodule method amounts to doing the first of these while also giving a hint that there's something missing (not the same as "there but encrypted").

Comment: "Anyone with a copy of the repository can see every object in the repository."

I agree with this. That's why the remote may not be an exact copy of the local repo. Instead certain files e.g. `top-secret.txt` have to be excluded from the remote. I hoped there would be some trick to achieve this e.g. by blacklisting files for _pushing_ (similiar to using `.gitignore` in order to exclude/blacklist files from _committing_).

Comment: @Joshua: no, in general git has no security model at all.  It relies on external programs to supply any required security.  There is *one* slight exception that crept in a while ago: one git command, `git archive`, will not allow arbitrary SHA-1 IDs any more as starting points unless you set a configuration flag.  But most git code, including everything at the object level, has no protection / exclusion: it's just not in there.  Retrofitting a security model would be hard and there seems little demand (perhaps chicken-and-egg, too bothersome = no one does it = no demand = too bothersome...).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Would it be too difficult to provide a script which clones the repo, removes all recent changes related to `top-secret.txt` (by iterating through unpushed commits) and then pushes to the remote?

Comment: As described, that might be easy, but would not be secure.  You must not only clean out the commits but also remove any hidden (reflog) references and then repack everything, to make sure the removed data is really removed.  (Normally they should not get transferred but I have seen cases where apparently-unreachable objects wound up on the server anyway, though this was back in the days of git 1.5.x and 1.6.x.)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a subfolder to contain your secret file, and create a local git repo in that directory, i.e. `git init mysecretsubdir`. Then add `mysecretsubdir/` to your `.gitignore`, so that it doesn't ever get committed to the main repository. This allows you to keep a version history your secret file, without sharing it with others.

Granted this approach is a bit hacky, but git is not really built to do what you are asking. One other thing you could do is create a [filter](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) that automatically encrypts your file when it goes into the index, and decrypts it when it goes into your working directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If git does not provide a simple solution for this I would prefer creating a `git submodule` to separate secret files from the main repository.